# Get reference to old view android

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to know how to keep the state of the view(textview) after the activity is destroyed.Suppose i have started Activity A with a textview and if i opened a Activity B then Activity A is destroyed (because i have checked only keep one activity at a time from developer options).So now  when i again come on Activity A the textView is initailized but when i do setText on textView its not setting the text as new reference to textview is created but the setText() method is refrenced by the old textView.So in this case what should i do.

Comment: You better put some codes you have done

Comment: Code there in normal i have just initialized the textView and setting a value